# How to use chrome breakpoint debugging tools with VueJS?

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, vim, nuxt.js

I develop with VIM, and I am trying to find a way to use chrome breakpoints for my frontend [Vue.js](https://vi.vuejs.org/) app. I'm also using [nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/) to develop my app with Vue.

Has anyone been able to successfully set a breakpoint in chrome without having to use [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) as their editor? If so what changes did they have to make?

For clarity's sake, I have of course tried entering `debugger` into my JS code, and I have also clicked on the left side of the source file in the chrome to apply a breakpoint on a particular line. Neither of these ways of applying a breakpoint have worked for me.

Comment: And? What was the solution?

Answer (score 1):

As I know There 2 way to use break point in these framework :

First, add debugger; in your code where you want like below:

```
  methods: {
    test() {
      let x = 15 * 5
      debugger
      //// other code
    }
  },
```

Second, open developer mode in source file found the place you want to have break point and click left side of it :)

Comment: Hi sorry soroush, perhaps I was not clear enough in my question. I will update my question -- of course I have tried `debugger` and opening up the source in the browser and applied a breakpoint.

Comment: Probably you have something like linting tools that remove debugger from your code